# PEAK chunk information

Tags: c#, wav

I am writing some code to read in wav files from an audio acquisition unit, and currently I am inspecting the "chunks" in the file (prior to the "data" chunk).  I have come across a chunk called "Peak", however, I have no idea what the bytes of data mean.  Can anyone please explain to me what the 16 bytes of data (for a 1-ch wave file) are?

Currently, I read the chunk ID as "PEAK" (in ASCII format), then read 4 bytes following that which returns an Int32 value of 16, so assuming 16 bytes of data following.  Is this correct?

Comment: From https://www.dsprelated.com/showthread/comp.dsp/81658-1.php, I get the unfortunately removed link which The Wayback Machine has at https://web.archive.org/web/20081201144551/http://music.calarts.edu/~tre/PeakChunk.html . There is also [this](https://code.google.com/archive/p/awesome-wav/wikis/WAVFormat.wiki)

Comment: Many thanks @NetMage!  Super helpful resources.  There enough information in them for anyone to understand the contents of the Peak chunk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Manually updating my question as "Answered" as I can't flag the comment provided by NetMage as the answer.  Please see comment by NetMage for the answer to my original question.  Thanks!